# Connect to web service error Connection Failure: Status code unavailable:

Tags: coldfusion

We are making a `cfhttp` call to connect to an https web service.
We are getting the this error:

```
Connection Failure: Status code unavailable
```

I searched Google but have found no solutions.

From the production server I am able to hit the web service URL.

I am a .Net developer and I am not sure of this technology.

Any pointers will be helpful.

Here is the line of code we are using to make the connection:

```
<cfhttp url="#arguments.TheIP#" method="post" throwonerror="true" timeout="45">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="SOAPACTION" value="#arguments.TheHeader#">
    <cfhttpparam type="XML" value="#arguments.TheXML#">
</cfhttp>
```

Comment: Add a sample of the code you are using.  Usually it can be dealt with setting a simple Java setting under the covers.

Comment: sorry i dint get you, the code that i have mentioned is the place where the call is happening, what java setting are you talking about, could you provide few references.

Comment: Any suggestion regarding the same problem if I'm using Soap 1.1 and CF 8 ? I am facing the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hum... First thing that appears odd is your IP argument as mentioned by barnyr. The response you are getting makes me think you are getting *NO* response at all (the request is completely ignored, not just erring). So some setting is causing them to ignore your request.

As of CF9 I use cfscript to do this kind of thing via HTTP when I can't use regular webservice java object proxy stubs.

Here is a working SOAP call via http() (because of .net to cf inability to communicate complex object hash maps via regular soap I resorted to this, among other things).

This is a cf to .net service call so it might be relevant for you as they are using just the built in tools to gen their SOAP service which was not perfectly Axis 1 SOAP happy-go-lucky.
In particular I had to play with some of the extra settings and headers to get it just so and specifically add the soap action into a header (which is usually derived from the SOAP body envelope).

Additionally, I am using oasis security which I had to stuff inside the envelope/body.

Here is the code (inside a cfc) that you might try updated as you need:

```
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // BUILD HTTP REQUEST
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        Local['SoapAction'] = "XYZ.Commercial.Mapping.ServiceContracts/IService/#Arguments.szMethodName#"; // THIS IS CASE SENSITIVE
        var oH = new Http();
        oH.setMethod('post');
        oH.setCharset('utf-8');
        oH.setUserAgent('Axis/1.2.1');
        oH.setTimeout(30);
        oH.setURL(Arguments.szURL);
        // INCLUDING THE SOAPACTION AS A HEADER IS SPECIFIC TO XYZ - USUALLY THE OPERATION IS DECIPHERED FROM THE ENVELOPE BODY TAGS - XYS REQUIRES THIS PATHING TO MATCH FOR THE SOAP ACTION HEADER VALUE
        oH.addParam(type="HEADER", name="SOAPAction", value='#Local.SoapAction#'); 
        oH.addParam(type="HEADER", name="Content-Type", value='text/xml');
        oH.addParam(type="body", value=Arguments.szBody);
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // EXECUTE HTTP
        Local['rsHttpSend']= oH.send();
        // SET RESULTS
        Local.nStatusCode = val(Local.rsHttpSend.getPrefix().StatusCode);
        Local.szResponse = Local.rsHttpSend.getPrefix().FileContent;
        Local.szHeader = Local.rsHttpSend.getPrefix().Header;
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

This approach was coupled with using SoapUI to verify the final soap body post was valid. So if you can do that too, you should be able to use this vector.

Let me know if you get any farther.

Comment: Thanks for your response, What I observed from WireShark is I see a "Certificate Unknown error", I have updated the cert to using the Keytool, still I am getting the same error. I am using "coldfusion mx 7" version. I am not at all aware of this CF technology, I am believing some setting would fix this issue

Comment: Also to debug I pasted some HTML comments in cfm files, these are not getting updated when i view page source, I did an iisreset and it alos dint help, how to build these files ? wont they get reflected immediately ?

Comment: Ah, CF7. You will be limited to the tag version which is slightly more cumbersome to get at those settings. 1) After setting a java cert (like when using keytool) you have to restart the coldfusion service. The jvm (JRun) won't load a lot of things up at the java level except on a full jvm restart.

Comment: 2) If you don't see comments or other things in your output/page updating, you need to make sure your template cache is cleared. If the templates are part of an object ( a cfc ) you also need to make sure your object cache is cleared. These settings are in the CFAdmin (Server Administration) pages. The template cache will typically also reset on service restart, but if you have the cfc class objects caching turned on, it will persist between restarts/reboots. I recommend only having these turned on (caching on) on production servers where you want the speed & few/rare changes are expected.

Comment: 3) No, to be clear the IIS service and the ColdFusion service are not the same. IIS just hands off traffic to the CF service. The empty response you are getting is a symptom of the cert issue not being resolved.

Comment: I did a test, In CFHttp i passed the plain URL, i did not pass any XML value, and I see a "connection Failure error", If i examine this in Wireshark i see certificate unknown error, Any pointers

Comment: Yes, that means your certificate is not properly installed. You are getting the equivalent of the invalid certificate warning you see in your browser for a bad cert site. You need to try to [re]install the cert in your java store. The jvm via cfhttp makes its own 'browser client' call and it is getting stuck on that error. Since it is a face-less request, there is no human to click on 'okay, I will trust that cert'. So you (the jvm) is not even really issuing your cfhttp request. You have to get the cert installed. With CF7 you may also need to install the whole chain of trusted authorities.

Comment: Thank you, that worked like a charm, I wonder how this got expired all of a sudden,

Answer (score 2):

I have faced / solved this a few times, the snippet below hopefully will work for you.  I highly recommend learning about it in stead of simply trying it.

I place this in my Application.cfc, but you could put it right in your script right before the cfhttp call as well.

```
<!--- fix for HTTPS connection failures --->
<cfif NOT isDefined("Application.sslfix")>
    <cfset objSecurity = createObject("java", "java.security.Security") />
    <cfset objSecurity.removeProvider("JsafeJCE") />
    <cfset Application.sslfix = true />
</cfif>enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a list of things to check:

- The variable for the URL is TheIP. Make sure this actually a properly
  formatted URL, not just a URL.
- Check that the target server's certificate is installed in the JVM's
  trust store. in Windows and I think .Net, the system's own
  certificate store is used, so if your browser can get to the URL
  you're ok. In Java there is a file which contains a list of Trusted
  Certs. Instructions on importing those certs are in the [CF docs for
  CFHTTP](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ffc.html).
- Check the ColdFusion logs for evidence of failure.
  c:\coldfusion9\logs\exception.log is probably a good place to start.

Comment: I have checked the URL, it looks fine, I have also imported the latest certificate, and i dont find and logs, to test this i am adding some HTML comments in myfile.cfm so that i could view form page source,  i dont see the comments that i mentioned, i also tried IIS reset

Comment: Thanks for your response, What I observed from WireShark is I see a "Certificate Unknown error", I have updated the cert to using the Keytool, still I am getting the same error. I am using "coldfusion mx 7" version.

Comment: when you imported the cert using keytool, did you import the parent certificates in the chain. If you're on CF7, the list of root certs is likely quite old. When you examine the cert in IE, go to the Certification Path tab, pick the next level up, click view certificate, then save that and import it into your keystore. repeat for each cert up the chain, including the root one. then re-try your CFHTTP. Make sure to restart ColdFusion after the imports in order to have it pick up the changes

Comment: I did a test, In CFHttp i passed the plain URL, i did not pass any XML value, and I see a "connection Failure error", If i examine this in Wireshark i see certificate unknown error, Any pointers

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your cfhttp link is correct. I face this issue and it totally based on incorrect cfhttp link.